# Need help creating a loop that calls a function with the right arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

nsetools is the library used to fetch the stock quotes

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()

#Names of stocks
stocks = {
    "APLAPOLLO" : 878.2,
    "AVANTIFEED": 488.95,
    "BALAMINES": 308.95
}
#Quantities of stocks
qty = {
    "APLAPOLLO": 10,
    "AVANTIFEED": 10,
    "BALAMINES": 10
}

def get_closing(stock):
    """
    Function to obtain closePrice of stocks
    """
    return nse.get_quote(stock)['closePrice']

#The function I am having problem with
def expenses_calc(buy, sell, qty):
    stt = 0.10
    ttc = 0.00325
    service_tax = 15.0
    sebi_charges = 0.0002
    swacch_bharat_cess = 0.02
    stamp_duty = 0.01

    turnover = (buy * qty) + (sell * qty)
    stt_total = (stt / 100) * turnover
    total_tran_charge = (ttc / 100) * turnover
    service_tax = (service_tax / 100) * total_tran_charge
    sebi_charges = (sebi_charges / 100) * turnover
    stamp_duty = (stamp_duty / 100) * turnover
    total_tax_and_charges = stt_total + total_tran_charge + service_tax + sebi_charges + stamp_duty
    total_investment = buy * qty
    current_value = sell * qty
    net_profit = (sell * qty) - (buy * qty) - total_tax_and_charges
```

How do I create a loop that calls expenses_calc function & replaces the arguments with the buy price & qty from the respective dictionaries and replaces the sell price with the close price obtained from get_closing function for each stock in the dictionary?

```
#expenses_calc(buy price from stocks dict, 
#sell price from get_closing func, qty from qty dict) 
#in a loop for each stock in the dictionary
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please fix your question, put in more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the opening price for your stocks is listed in the stocks dictionary. In this case, you want to iterate over the `dict.keys()`:

```
for key in stocks.keys():
    buy_price = stocks[key]
    sell_price = get_closing(key)
    stock_qty = qty[key]

    expenses_calc(buy_price, sell_price, stock_qty)
```

I'm not sure what your `expenses_calc` function is supposed to do - return something, or print it out - but add in a variable assignment as appropriate.

This code uses the `stocks` dictionary keys to pull data from that dictionary, the `qty` dictionary, and from the `get_closing()` function, assuming everything is keyed to the same stock name.

Comment: I plan to find the net profit if all stocks are sold at the closing price after the taxes/expenses are deducted.

Comment: Well, based on your question, this should do what you want. Please try it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: It works, can you help me with getting the sum of all net profits. It creates separate net profit for each stock due to the loop.

Comment: As mentioned at the end of my answer, you need to return the value of the net profit at the end of the `expenses_calc` function, and assign it to a variable. By the way, since you're new to StackOverflow, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I created a variable "net_profit = (sell * qty) - (buy * qty) - total_tax_and_charges" in expenses_calc function. It calculates this individually for each stock, how do I store it each time to sum it up later?

Comment: @Dana, these are very basic programming questions. Please read https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html and learn how to **return values from functions**, and then try it. If you can't make it work, please come back and post a *new* question showing what you've tried.